# How to resolve this image cut issue in iPhone 8?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

**iPhone 8**

[image: iPhone 8]

**iPhone 11**

[image: iPhone 11]

How to resolve this image cut issue in iPhone 8 ?

Time icon cutting from bottom side

Already tried with

```
dateImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
dateImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_Time").withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -0.5, right: 0))
```

But it's not working

Comment: There are two possibilities.

1. You @2x image has already cut
2. In aspect fill mode image will spread so,Set dateImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit or dateImage

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved with set `contentMode = .center`

And

```
dateImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_Date").withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0.5, right: 0))
```

Now it's look better in **iPhone 8**

[image]